# Toggle jQuery .load with .click

Tags: jquery, html, load, click

Hey I have a div `content` that I want to load external html files into. When I click on a link in my nav:

```
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="logo">
                <strong>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Sam Jarvis logo"/>
                    </a>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#work">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#clients">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

I want to fade in an external html file per link. If I click home, index.html fades in. If I click another page, the previous page fades out and the new one fades in.

I'm not sure why my current link isn't popping up an alert box. How do I target individual links with jQuery like in my menu ul?

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".menu ul li a").click(function(){
                alert("Execute");
          });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're including jQuery Migrate, not jQuery. Try using

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

When you include jQuery, it works fine: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PsZVR/)**

[jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#readme) is a jQuery plugin that helps you update old code to the newer version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to add `jQuery` reference.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".menu ul li a").click(function(){
                alert("Execute");
          });
     });
</script>
```